# Python TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)

Tags: python, arrays

Im trying to take numbers from num.txt(1 3 2) and set it into a array

```
from array import *
import sys    
f = open('num.txt', 'r')  
l = f.readlines() 
f.close() 
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]
sclist = [l]
myArray = array('i', [])
myArray.fromlist(sclist)
for i in myArray:
    print(i)
```

It returns

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```

If I change it to myArray.fromlist(int(sclist)) I get

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: why you want to use array here, cant you do things wiht list?

Comment: 1.) Why do you think you need an `arrary.array`? What's wrong with a simple `list`?  2). What's the purpose of `list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]`? BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, as that shadows the built-in `list` type. 3). `sclist = [l]` puts a list of lists of strings into `sclist`. I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file contains one number per line, you could change the assignment to sclist to:

```
sclist = [int(s) for s in l]
```

Hopefully that will work.  I also suggest that you avoid using "list" as a variable name (unused in this example), since that will mask the standard Python definition and could cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is that `l = f.readlines()` will return a list of strings, which you then put in another list `sclist = [l]`, so just do `myArray.fromlist(l)`.
Make sure to convert the content you read from the file to int prior to doing the `myArray.fromlist(l)` call.

Comment: Still get    TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)